# Request scope bean and lifecycle lazy loading

Tags: jsf, request, lazy-loading, managed-bean

I have a request scope bean with a method to retrieve some data for displaying purposes.
The method has **multiple parameters** so that it can get called on different occasions, also in the same view.

JSF:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.data('foo')}"/>
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.data('bar')}"/>
```

Bean:

```
public Object[] doSomething(Object arg)
{
    Object[] data = //hit database or remote server to retrieve data;
    return data;
}
```

This works fine of cause, but the method is **invoked multiple times** for each `#{bean.data(obj)}` because of the jsf lifecycle phases.

I only want to hit the database once for each usage of `#{bean.data(obj)}`.

I tried lazy loading using following code which is not working: Now no data is displayed on my jsf page.

```
private Object[] data;

public Object[] doSomething(Object arg)
{
    if (this.data == null)
        this.data = //hit database or remote server to retrieve data;
    return this.data;
}
```

Is viewscope a to wide scope since the method is called multiple times on a view using different parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get hold of it in a `Map`.

```
private Map<Object, Object[]> datas = new HashMap<Object, Object[]>();

public Object[] getData(Object arg) {
    Object[] data = datas.get(arg);

    if (data == null) {
        data = //hit database or remote server to retrieve data;
        datas.put(arg, data);
    }

    return data;
}
```